# Append html data with inline script html data and to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append table data with html inside script. And append data for print

but here the table data is only shows in the print mode.

**html**

```
 <div>
    <p>Your content here</p>
    <table  id="toPrint">
     <tr>
    <td>Neil D'zousa</td>
    <td>112233445566</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="notForPrint">
    <a href="#" id="print">print</a>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function open() {
 var w = window.print();
 var htmlTable2 = '<tr>' + '<th>Name</th>'
              + '<th>Phone</th>'+ '</tr>';
    var html = $("#toPrint").html();
    var t=html;
    $(t).append(htmlTable2);
    $(w.document.body).html(t);
}
$(function() {
    $("a#print").click(open);
});
```

if anyone knew about this please share your answer.

with regards ...

Comment: As far as I know what you're trying to do isn't possible, the print window can't be modified on it's own, other than setting styles for print only etc. but that's not really the same. The `w` variable in your code probably returns the current window, not a *special* print window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5fb970u9/)

```
var htmlTable2 = '<tr>' + '<th>Name</th>'
          + '<th>Phone</th>'+ '</tr>';
var html1 = $("#toPrint").append(htmlTable2);
var t=html1;
$(t).append(htmlTable2);
window.print();
```

Try this. I tested in chrome. It works fine

EDIT:
   Response to your req: You have to chack whether dom[name,etc] is already [resent

```
$('#domHeader').length > 0 means already present.

if(! $('#domHeader').length)
{
 var htmlTable2 = '<tr>' + '<th>Name</th>'
          + '<th>Phone</th>'+ '</tr>';
 var html1 = $("#toPrint").prepend(htmlTable2); //peter is correct
 //var t=html1;
 //$(t).append(htmlTable2);
}
```

[EDITED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5fb970u9/2/)

[UPDATE FINAL](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5fb970u9/3/)

Comment: the table head increments with each click

Comment: @prasanth, thats what you have added in your code. You have to modify it. Whenever you click print, it ll b appended. Isnt? This si what you have done in your code. wait i ll modify it

Comment: yeah i see it. and thank you.. but there is one problem that the header shows 2 times top and down

Comment: See now @Prasanth. It's due to double appending

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it. The headers should be at the top:

```
function open() {

     var htmlTable2 = '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>';
     var html1 = $("#toPrint").prepend( htmlTable2 );

     window.print(); 
}
```

The rest of your code should work fine.